# Gmock setting out parameter

Tags: c++, googlemock

In a GMock test method, I need to set the out parameter to a variable's address, so that the out parameter of `dequeue()`, which is `data` points to the variable `ch`:

```cpp
MOCK_METHOD1(dequeue, void(void* data));

char ch = 'm';
void* a = (void*)&ch;

EXPECT_CALL(FQO, dequeue(_))
    .WillOnce(/*here I need to set argument to a*/);
```

I tried to figure out [side effects](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_7_CheatSheet#Side_Effects) but keep getting an error.

Comment: Please add the error you're seeing to your question so that it's easier to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the *output parameter* of a function to point to a `void*`, then its type needs to be `void**`:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(dequeue, void(void** data));
```

otherwise, you can only return the *value* but not a *pointer to a value* through the output parameter.

If you make the appropriate change to the signature of your `dequeue()` method and the call to `MOCK_METHOD1()`, then this should do what you want:

```
EXPECT_CALL(FQO, dequeue(_))
    .WillOnce(SetArgPointee<0>(a));
```